# Generating Dataframe from JSON URL in a column in another DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to generate one dataframe based on Json Url in another Dataframe called Data

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

resp = requests.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/stock/list')
txt = resp.json()
Data = pd.DataFrame(txt['symbolsList'])
Data = Data.assign(keymetric= 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company-key-metrics/'+ Data.symbol + '?period=quarter')
Data = Data.assign(profile= 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/'+ Data.symbol)
Data = Data.assign(financials= 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financial-statement-growth/'+ Data.symbol + '?period=quarter')
```

I have 3 problems:

1) when I am downloading the JSON URL in the Dataframe ('Data') I don't have in the output the symbol 
in the code below 'AAPL'

```
resp = requests.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company-key-metrics/AAPL?period=quarter')
txt = resp.json()
key= pd.DataFrame(txt['metrics'])
```

2) I don't know how to automate the code above, using as an import the column 'keymetrics' in the dataframe 'Data'

3) once the process is done I am trying to have just one dataframe instead of having one per each symbol

Expected output for keymetrics. Each column should be divided not all aggregated under one column called 'keymetric'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can work.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/stock/list')
txt = resp.json()
Data = pd.DataFrame(txt['symbolsList'])

def get_value(symbol):
    resp_keymetric = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company-key-metrics/{symbol}?period=quarter')
    resp_profile = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/{symbol}?period=quarter')
    resp_financials = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financial-statement-growth/{symbol}?period=quarter')
    try:
        txt_keymetric = resp_keymetric.json()['metrics'][0]
        txt_profile = resp_profile.json()['profile']
        txt_financials = resp_financials.json()['growth'][0]
        df_keymetric = pd.DataFrame([txt_keymetric])
        df_profile = pd.DataFrame([txt_profile])
        df_financials = pd.DataFrame([txt_financials])
        df = pd.concat([df_keymetric, df_profile, df_financials], axis=1)
        return df
    except:
        pass

result = []
for symbol in Data['symbol'].values.tolist()[:5]:
    try:
        df = get_value(symbol)
        result.append(df)
    except:
        pass

result_df = pd.concat(result, axis=0)
print(result_df)
```

Comment: it is working, but it does not show the data correctly.
I tried to fix it using this code, but it is not working. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Nope, I still got the same format. It does not recognize each column as a column, but put everything under 'metrics', 'profile', 'financial'

Comment: posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Expected output for keymetrics. Each column should be divided not all aggregated under one column called 'keymetric'

[image]

current output 
[image]